# JRXML operator error

Tags: templates, operators, jasper-reports

I'm getting this error when compiling my JRXML file in iReport 3.1.2:

`com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@f1cdfb The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignExpression@eb40fe`

The only place in my entire report where I use the operator > is here:

```xml
<parameter name="dynamicSectionCondition" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[($P{sectionId} != null && $P{sectionId} > new Integer("0")) ? new String("AND loctn_sctn_id = " + $P{sectionId}) : new String("")]]>
    </defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Google hasn't been my friend on that one. Any Jasper template expert out there has a vague idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to compare 2 Integers in the JRXML. Instead of doing this:

```
$P{sectionId} > new Integer("0")
```

The solution is this:

```
$P{sectionId}.compareTo(new Integer("0")) != 0
```

That looks a little convoluted but it works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this monologue between you and yourself Sir Lancelot, is ages old and originating in medival times, I have to give a fair warning to travelers which might want to take this ancient lore to their library.

If you want to know if $P{sectionId} is bigger than new Integer("0"), then your solution would yield true, even when $P{sectionId} is smaller than new Integer("0").

Cause:

```
(new Integer("-5")).compareTo(new Integer("0"))
```

would result in:

```
-1
```

which would not be 0 as in:

```
$P{sectionId}.compareTo(new Integer("0")) != 0
```

and therefore the condition would be also **true**.

Just use:

```
$P{sectionId}.compareTo(new Integer("0")) == 1
```

Remember:

```
x.compareTo(0) == 1 (if x > 0)
x.compareTo(0) == 0 (if x == 0)
x.compareTo(0) == -1 (if x < 0)
```

Sorry if you already know the basics and your 2nd post was just to show a common way of solving the problem, but I thought if a newbie is reading your first post, he/she maybe assumes, that one is able to find numbers bigger than 0, with the posted solution.